# MongoDB Aggregation, how to return unaffected items

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a collection where the data looks like this

```
{
    "fname":"bob",
    "lname":"jones",
    "role":"professional", 
    "active":true,
    "jobs":[{
        "job":"janitor",
        "current":true
    },{
        "job":"dog groomer"
        "current":false
    }]
}
```

I am using "aggregate" to concatenate and cull some data that is not needed on the display side - and returning a simplified array of objects.

```
People.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "role": "professional", "active": true }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": { "$concat": ["$fname", " ", "$lname"] },
    "jobs": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$jobs",
        "as": "job",
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$job.current", true] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { 
    "name": 1, 
    "job": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$jobs.job", 0] }
  }}
])
```

However, I want to pass back other items in the People object too.
Do they need to be passed thru the entire pipeline?
If I add the fields to the first $project too - then only one of them comes back...

so now THIS

```
People.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "role": "professional", "active": true }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": { "$concat": ["$fname", " ", "$lname"] },
    "jobs": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$jobs",
        "as": "job",
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$job.current", true] }
      }
    },
    "role":"$role",
    "active":"$active"
  }},
  { "$project": { 
    "name": 1, 
    "job": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$jobs.job", 0] },
    "role":"$role",
    "active":"$active"
  }}
])
```

Gives me:

```
name 
job 
role
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) instead of [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with exclusion to drop the lname and fname field.

So something like

```
People.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"role":"professional","active":true}},
  {"$addFields":{
    "name":{"$concat":["$fname"," ","$lname"]},
    "job":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{
          "jobs":{
            "$arrayElemAt":[
              {"$filter":{
                "input":"$jobs",
                "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.current",true]}
              }},
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "in":"$$jobs.job"
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$project":{"fname":0,"lname":0}}
])
```